# How to omit some numbers from rand() function's range?

Tags: c++

I need to use `rand()` function to get numbers between 1-15, so I simply used the function as below.

```
num1 = rand()%15+1;
```

But between this 1-15 range, there are some numbers that I want to prevent from being assigned into `num1` variable.

I thought about putting an `if-else` function there, as the `rand()` function would repeat itself on such occasion that an undesired number turned up.

However, what I'm most curious is whether there is a more effective way to omit these undesired numbers from `rand()` function's range.

Thank you so much!

Comment: You question is not specific.  Why are you using `%` on the rand?  Do you want integer values?  What is the range being excluded?

Comment: You should refrain from selectively  dropping values returned from rand as this will most certainly affect the statistical properties of the pseudo random number sequence. Instead follow the path outlined in owacoder's answer (use all values, map them onto the needed domain).

Comment: @collapsar Using the mod trick with rand doesn't usually give an even distribution either and rand is notoriously poorly implemented on many compilers, that I would question if it is worth worrying about that. Any serious requirement for pseudo-random numbers won't use rand! Hopefully OP knows that.

Answer (score 6):

A very simple solution: call `rand()` with a modulo value equal to the total count of numbers in your output range. Then define a mapping function to map values into your required specific output ranges.

For example: to get a random value between 1 and 5 or 11 and 15, inclusive:

```
int map(int val)
{
    if (val > 5)
        return val+5;
    else
        return val;
}

int value = rand()%10+1;
value = map(value);
```

Answer (score 5):

Sounds that you want to have e.g. a random number of the set { 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 14, 15 } (isn't it)?

So, for this example, this is a count of 8 different values and you can do it like this:

```
lookupTable[] = { 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 14, 15 };
num1 = lookupTable[rand() % 8];
```

I'd placed a running example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a0cb4f052e0af11).

Answer (score 3):

To get real random numbers between 1 and 15, you can use such C++11 code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main()
{
        std::random_device rd;
        std::mt19937 mt(rd());
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(1, 15);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        std::cout << dist(mt) << ", ";

}
```

To remove some of this number you can use `map` as suggested owacoder
Also you see video (from MS guy who wrote part of VS STL) about how to get real random number, and why `rand` can not be used for that:

https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful